# Java Swing: how do the new instance work?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I've one stupid question for you. 
In the costructor of A, i do a new B(), what is the logical thread that the variable p is a JPanel with the features of paintComponent'method?

```
    public class A extends JFrame{
       private B p=null;


       public A(){
          setTitle("New GUI");
          setSize(300,300);
          setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
          add( p=new B() );
       }

        private class B extends JPanel{ 
          public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
             super.paintComponent(g);
             g.drawString( "Hello World", 150, 150 );
          }
       }

public class C{
   public static void main( String []args ){
          EventQueue.invokeLater( new Runnable(){
              public void run(){
                  JFrame fr=new A();
                  f.setVisible(true);             
              }
          });      
   }
  }
```

If you want more information to understand my question I'm here ;)
Thanks.

Comment: The better question is: why do you extend `JFrame` instead of just using it in the first place?

Comment: You should perform the setSize method **after** the add method in A.  JFrame methods have to be executed in a certain order.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc the code correctly work with setSize(x,y) before add. What is it possible?

Comment: @TimothyTruckle this version is correct for you?

Comment: it works because you are calling the setSize() method of A which was inherited from JFrame

Comment: @muhammad ok, and in that cases can it fail?

Comment: No, is it failing?

Comment: nono but @GilbertLeBlanc saw that there is an error, but I don't understand why